# What is the correct way of cleaning up resources using ResourceT?

Tags: sockets, haskell, resources, conduit

I've been playing around with `conduit-extra`'s UNIX package, which basically allows for an easy creation of a server using UNIX domain sockets, specifically using the [`runUnixServer` funciton](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.0.3/docs/Data-Conduit-Network-Unix.html#g:3).

The problem is that after the function exists it doesn't cleanup the socket file, which means it needs to be cleaned up manually. Here's a simple example, which basically creates an echo server.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let settings = serverSettings "foobar.sock"
  runUnixServer settings (\ad -> (appSource ad) $$ (appSink ad))
```

I've google around a bit and found that the correct way to handle the resources here is by using the [`resourcet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet) package. Though the problem is that most of the APIs in resources expect me to allocate the resource myself, which isn't the case of `runUnixSever`, which doesn't return anyhting.

At first I thought I could use `register`, to register a function that removes the file, such as the following

```
main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
  register $ removeLink "foobar.sock"
  let settings = serverSettings "foobar.sock"
  liftIO $ runUnixServer settings (\ad -> (appSource ad) $$ (appSink ad))
```

There's a problem with this approach though, at least as far as the documentation for `allocate` says:

> This is almost identical to calling the allocation and then registering the release action, but this properly handles masking of asynchronous exceptions.

Does this mean that `register` in itself doesn't handle asynchronous exceptions? If so, could that be a problem when one of the handlers spawned by the `runUnixServer` (docs say it spawns a thread for each client) raises an error?

A third and final solution that I came up with is by using `allocate`, in order to make sure that the asynchronous exceptions are handled properly (I'm not sure if it is really necessary in this case).

```
main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
  allocate (return 1) (const $ removeLink "foobar.sock")
  let settings = serverSettings "foobar.sock"
  liftIO $ runUnixServer settings (\ad -> (appSource ad) $$ (appSink ad))
```

But is this really the best solution? Since I'm creating a value which I'll never use `(return 1)` and then using a `const` function to ignore that value in the finalizer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before addressing the `resourcet` question:

1. `resourcet` is not needed in this case. You can just use the `finally` function for something like this, e.g. `runUnixServer settings (\ad -> ...)`finally`removeLink "foobar.sock"`.
2. This actually looks like problematic behavior. The generally accepted pattern in conduit is that, if you allocate a resource, you're responsible for cleaning it up. I didn't write the unix socket code, so there might be a reason for the author to have done it differently here. But it's worth opening up a bug report.

That said, your initial code with `register` is fine. The only problem I see is if an exception is thrown before `foobar.sock` is created, though my `finally` solution is vulnerable to that too.

The comment about allocate vs register has to do with code that looks like the following:

```
handle <- openFile fp ReadMode
register $ hClose handle
```

This code is vulnerable to an async exception being thrown between the `openFile` and `register` calls. Since you are not allocating a resource like this, `register` is fine.

Comment: Thanks for a super quick response!